# Execute Function Once per Unique Value

Tags: postgresql, function

I have two tables that contain data related to everyday business:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
  main_id serial,
  cola text,
  colb text,
  colc text,
  CONSTRAINT main_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (main_id)
);

CREATE TABLE second_table (
  second_id serial,
  main_id integer,
  cold text,
  CONSTRAINT second_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (second_id),
  CONSTRAINT second_table_fkey FOREIGN KEY (main_id)
    REFERENCES main_table (main_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

We have a need to know when some data was updated in these tables so that exports can be generated and pushed to third parties. I've created a third table to hold the update information:

```
CREATE TYPE field AS ENUM ('cola', 'colb', 'colc', 'cold');
CREATE TABLE table_updates (
  main_id int,
  field field
  updated_on date NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  CONSTRAINT table_updates_fkey FOREIGN KEY (main_id)
    REFERENCES main_table (main_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

`main_table` has a trigger to update `table_updates` before `UPDATE` queries, which satisfies the need to track three of the four column updates.

I can easily add the same type of trigger to `second_table`, however because `main_id` is not unique the function can be executed several times for a single `main_id` value, which is not desirable.

How can I create a function that, when updating several rows in `second_table`, executes only once per `main_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create a function that, when updating several rows in second_table, executes only once per main_id?

If your inserts are batched insert by main_id ie, `INSERT INTO tbl (main_id...) VALUES (main_id ...),(main_id ...),(main_id ...)` you can use the [rule system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-triggers.html) to trigger once for the `INSERT` or `UPDATE`

> For the things that can be implemented by both, which is best depends on the usage of the database. **A trigger is fired once for each affected row. A rule modifies the query or generates an additional query.** So if many rows are affected in one statement, a rule issuing one extra command is likely to be faster than a trigger that is called for every single row and must re-determine what to do many times. However, the trigger approach is conceptually far simpler than the rule approach, and is easier for novices to get right.

Shy of that, you may also want to look into the normal [`LISTEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html), and [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-notify.html). Which give you the ability to use Async actions. If that's your thing and you decide to keep the trigger method consider Trigger Change Notification module, via [`tcn`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tcn.html).

My suggestion is to do this in the app (outside of the DB) if at all possible. Remember in PostgreSQL `temp` tables are local to the session. So you can have each loader-session do something like this,

```
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE UNLOGGED etl_inventory;
  COPY foo FROM stdin;
  -- Are they different, if so `NOTIFY`
  -- UPSERT
COMMIT;
```

And then one have one daemon that does exportation add to exportation queue when it receives the `NOTIFY` event.

Answer (score 1):

While Evan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43376947/1555990) is correct, I think this question could benefit from an example.

This is the rule definition I used with the example tables in the question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE update_update_table
AS ON UPDATE TO second_table
DO ALSO (
  INSERT INTO table_updates (
    main_id, field
  )
  SELECT DISTINCT OLD.main_id, 'cold'::field
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TRUE
    FROM table_updates
    WHERE main_id = OLD.main_id
        AND field = 'cold'
  );
  UPDATE table_updates
  SET updated_on = NOW()
  WHERE main_id = OLD.main_id
    AND field = 'cold'
)
```